# Python Pandas: Concatenate and update dataframe values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this 2 dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
         'Product': ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'],
         'Price': [200, 300, 400],
         'Quantity': [10, 5, 20],
    }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Product','Price','Quantity'])

print(df1)

data2 = {
         'Product': ['product1','product2','product4'],
         'Price': [200, 1000,50],
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns= ['Product','Price'])
```

df1:

```
    Product  Price  Quantity
0  product1    200        10
1  product2    300         5
2  product3    400        20
```

df2:

```
    Product  Price
0  product1    200
1  product2   1000
2  product4     50
```

I search for concatening and updating both to obtain this dataframe:

```
    Product  Price  Quantity
0  product1    200       10
1  product2   1000       5
2  product3     -1       20
2  product4     50       NaN
```

This means that:

- New product in df2 (product4) has to be added with the available information (Price)
- Product which is not in df2 should be kept with Price set to -1
- Product in df1 and df2 has to only has his price updated (product2)
- All other Products are kept the same.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try [Left join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?

Comment: `Product which is not in df2 should be kept with Price set to -1` Worth mentioning that this implies that the price in df1 never affects the output dataframe. Either df2 overrides it, or df2 doesn't include it, so it will be set to -1. Is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a merge based solution:

- Get the `Quantity` value from `df1` by merging the two DataFrames on the `Product`.  The `Price` from `df1` is dropped so that those prices aren't added to the final DataFrame.  This is an outer merge to ensure the result has products from both `df1` and `df2`.
- The above step almost gets you to the desired result, except for needing to replace missing prices with `-1` and sorting based on product.

```
final = df2.merge(df1.drop('Price', axis=1), on='Product', how='outer')
final['Price'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
final.sort_values('Product', inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
    Product   Price  Quantity
0  product1   200.0      10.0
1  product2  1000.0       5.0
3  product3    -1.0      20.0
2  product4    50.0       NaN
```